# server dont start the session php

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

i've been working on a small website it was working perfect on my localhost but the problem is when i tried to put it online i had session problems i'm hosting it on ipage there dumb support didn't help at all, so my problem is this
on the top of evry page i call this :

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

i changed the :

```
session.save_path = "/var/php_sessions"
```

to:

`session.save_path = "/tmp"`

its worked for the first login, but when u refresh or navigate the session change to 1. i have no idea why??

i did some recherche i found that ipage requiere to use :

```
session_save_path("/home/users/web/b2894/ipg.sefroucom/cgi-bin/tmp");
```

others say it should be like this :

```
session_save_path("/home/users/web/b2894/ipg.sefroucom"/cgi-bin/tmp);
```

on the top of evry page now the twist is : if i add it to index page the others pages work fine but not the index page also if add it to an other page it stop working like the home page. 
its been 3 days now im getting realy fruasted i dont know what to do please help if somebody want to test it the link is here:

http://www.sefrou.com/

you can test it and see the problem.
 thankyou

Comment: Without seeing some of your code for how you set this in a page it would be just speculation on our part.

Comment: Did you make sure the `session_start();` is placed before any output?

Comment: yes its the first thing on the page no space nothing

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that their `session path` doesn't have `write permisions` for **"Others"** group. It must be  **777**.

I suggest you use **Cookies** (which will allow you do "permanent" logins) or change your webhosting server.

As far as what others say that `session_save_path("/home/users/web/b2894/ipg.sefroucom"/cgi-bin/tmp);` would be fit, i say **no**. That makes no sense for PHP, it will result in a fatal error.

Comment: What kind of system doesn't have `777` permissions on `/tmp`?

Comment: One recently configured. Maybe his account was allocated to a new server which doesn't have the right permissions. I recall having the same problem one a new Debian x64 / nginx web server.

Comment: I think lots of things would break if these permissions weren't set correctly.

Comment: It's just the sessions and the file uploading which will be broken. I'm working as tech analyst on server related issues and management and from my experience, didn't see anything else break while those permisions are not set.

Comment: I'm not just talking about your applications. Lots of other things on Unix expect `/tmp` to be world-writable.

Comment: Applications runing on Unix are using root as user, permissions for root user will always be at least `6` (`644`, `744` etc.), I think you don't fully understand the structure of permisions and their meaning.

Comment: I have been a Unix system administrator for about 25 years, I am very aware of the structure of permissions. Not everything runs as root.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54543/discussion-between-edduvs-and-barmar).

Comment: Your answer contains much missleading information and most of it is not even correct. I'd never suggest 777 for anything in a www directorty. Figure out what user you run and setup groups/permissions accordingly.

Comment: changing  the server is not an option for me now and about cookies im still new i barely could understand session and make it work on my local server what else i can di pleaz

Comment: @edduvs "*The problem is that their session path doesn't have write permisions for "Others" group. It must be 777.*" - only `/tmp` must have 777. I'd never give www directories ("*their session path*" - like you said) 777.

Comment: @DanFromGermany you're contradicting yourself, like i said, `their session path` is `/tmp`, go in your webserver folder, get `opendir` to path `/tmp` and you will see `/` refers to the root folder, not the curent folder. As `../` refers to the parent folder. `/tmp` means `root_folder/tmp`. `www` folder does NOT contain `/tmp`, so please learn some directory structuring in unix. It's the same for windows, please get a hold of an unix filesystem tutorial and read it.

Comment: okey so nothing working so far if i dont use the "session_save_path" i still get the thing working for the index without refreshing or going to another page so is there a way i can take that value and use it befor i do or go  somwhere else?

Comment: finely i did it well this the answer dont use that 
`session_save_path('"your home directory path"/cgi-bin/tmp');`

just change 

     session.save_path = "/var/php_sessions"

to:

   `session.save_path = "/tmp"`

and Ensure `register_globals` is off in the php.ini thats all thankyou evrybody.